# Перевод времени ответа сервера в секунды

Tags: время, php, mysql

У меня такой код для времени ответа Mysql. У меня бывает выдает такое время: `3.0994415283203E-6`

Что это время означает?

```
$starttime = microtime(true);
$endtime = microtime(true);
$duration = $endtime - $starttime;
```

Можно сделать через секунды? Нужны только первые 3 цифры, например: **0,65 сек.**
Помогите, пожалуйста!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Форматируете число как нужно ([`print`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.print.php) или [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php))  и добавляете к строке "сек."